# Unnable to resolve tycho v1.3.0(or any) for eclipse 2018-12

Tags: eclipse, maven

Trying to build eclipse plugin using tycho v1.3.0. And my eclipse is not PDE, its a Java/J2EE IDE with PDE plugin installed. My pom.xml is as below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
          http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.myeclipse.example</groupId>
<artifactId>com.myeclipse.example.id</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>eclipse-plugin</packaging>

<properties>
    <tycho-version>1.4.0</tycho-version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>2018-12</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${tycho-version}</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Do i need to configure p2 repository here? because maven is trying to download tycho from m2 repo and failed to download. If yes for eclipse 2018-12(i.e. 4.10.0) what is the p2 repo url?

**ERROR Received:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/eclipse/tycho/tycho-maven-plugin/1.3.0/tycho-maven-plugin-1.3.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Unresolveable build extension: Plugin org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:1.3.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0 @ 
[ERROR] Unknown packaging: eclipse-plugin @ line 10, column 13
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the tycho maven plugins are on maven central, you don't need a p2 repo for that. The p2 repo is used by tycho to resolve the plugin dependencies of your eclipse-plugin project.

I am using tycho 1.1.0 currently in a project, and there it works as expected, which pretty much the same configuration as in your example.